# Android VOICE_CALL, obsolete audio source

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a call recorder application, however, my audio source when it's MIC works fine, but it does not capture the second voice.

If I change to VOICE_CALL my app closes.

According to the android documentation, VOICE_CALL is obsolete, but I need to create my call recording application.

I see hundreds of similar apps in the PlayStore and wonder what the secret is for them to be able to record both sides of the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For privacy reasons you cannot directly get the call audio unless you're a system app.  Any app on the play store doing that is using the MIC and hoping it picks up.